# Failed opening required file: server.php

Tags: php, lumen

I am having the error as shown below using lumen 5.1.

> Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sample/server.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

I am using bash command line and using the `php artisan serve`. When running the `serve` on Git Bash I don't get any errors. However when I started to type `localhost:8000` in my browser I am getting the above error.

What can I do to solve this?